# Jackson object mapper - serialize non-primitive field into string

Tags: java, jackson

Given the following code:

```
class SomeType2 {
    public String a;
    public String b;
}

class SomeType1 {
    public String c;
    public SomeType2 d;
}

SomeType1 value = new SomeType1("c", new SomeType2("a", "b"));

objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
```

The above serialization should give me back

```
{
    "c": "c",
    "d": "{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":\"b\"}"
}
```

I scanned though all the jackson annotations and none of them seem to be able to achieve this.

Is custom serializer (and deserializer) my only hope to achieve this simple goal?

Comment: What does it currently give you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialise SomeType2 to a String rather than a normal JSON object you will need to define a custom de/serialiser.

Comment: I always try to avoid custom desers because their interface is not very clear to me and there are so many different base classes and I don't know which one is the best to extend from.

Answer (score 0):

After some improvements desirable behavoir is achieved:

```
public class Program {
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SomeType1 value = new SomeType1("c", new SomeType2("a", "b"));
        String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        System.out.println(s);

    }
    
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class SomeType2 {
        public String a;
        public String b;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class SomeType1 {
        public String c;
        public SomeType2 d;
    }
}
```

output is: **{"c":"c","d":{"a":"a","b":"b"}}**

At least you should provide constructors explicitly or using Lombok

Comment: Thanks for looking into this but your answer is incorrect - it is the default behaviour of jackson to serialize object field into map. I am looking into serializing object field into string.

Comment: Sorry. After few iterations of looking through queston I have caught your point. So i think that you want untypical behavior, which by default not provided by any of serializers. Generally, they keep your structure. And if you want to get another structure as outcome you should care about some changes before serializing. I mean, provide your variable d of SomeType1 as String, where in turn object should be casted to String  before by any means (overriding toString() or other)